# Sacar un numero entero de una cadena de char en c

Tags: c

Como puedo sacar el número de un string de 9 chars

```
char * str = "EJ:12345\n";
```

He intentado 
`sscanf (str,"EJ:%d\n",&n)` pero `n` parece valer 0

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Acabo de probar este código y funciona perfecto:

```
  char *str = "EJ:12345\n";
  int n;
  sscanf (str,"EJ:%d\n",&n);
  printf ("%d\n",n);
```

Revisa si no estás utilizando la variable "n" para otra cosa.
Saludos.